# SED command to replace certain string for the specific format

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I need to convert the below string

```
 TableName.Cust Name,
 Name,
 TableName.Name AS Name,
```

output should be like below

```
 TableName.Cust "Name",
 Name,
 TableName.Name AS "Name",
```

Hence I used below command

```
sed 's/[a-z][A-Z] Name,/ "Name",/gI'
```

but it is giving below output

```
TableName.Cu "Name",
Name,
TableName.Name "Name",
```

issue is here the word  "st" is removed in the first statement and "AS" is removed  in the 3 statement. 
could you please give proper command to replace this.

Comment: the preceding word will vary. it will not be always as "AS"

Comment: There are 3 kind of word. like below .  
name,  TableName.Name name,      TableName.Name as Name, 
the output should be like this
name,  TableName.Name "name",      TableName.Name as "Name", 

i mean the first statement should not modified.

Comment: i have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

this should do

```
$ sed '/TableName/s/Name,$/"&"/' infile
Name,
TableName.Name AS "Name,"
```

`$` is an anchor to point end of line, so `Name,$` matches 'Name,' at the end of the line and replace it with "Name,"

Comment: i have updated my query .plz provide command

Comment: Afshin, leverage `&` in replacement: `sed 's/Name$/"&"/'`

Comment: it is not working

Comment: can u plz look my question since i have updated my actual issue.

Comment: @KasiyA the OP's example *appears* to suffer from trailing whitespace - perhaps making the `$` anchor ineffective?

Comment: In that case this should work, sed '/TableName/s/Name,.*$/"&"/' infile, @asalthangam,   or with Name, instead sed '/TableName/s/Name,.*$/"Name,"/' infile

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this (for example, using capture groups) - possibly the simplest is to replace `Name,` case-insensitively **only** on those lines where it is preceded by a sequence of at least one word character and at least one whitespace character:

```
$ sed -E '/\w+\s+Name,/ s/Name,/"Name",/I' infile
  TableName.Cust "Name",
  Name,
  TableName.Name AS "Name",
```

or using basic regular expressions

```
$ sed '/[[:alnum:]_-]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]\{1,\}Name,/ s/Name,/"Name",/I' infile
  TableName.Cust "Name",
  Name,
  TableName.Name AS "Name",
```

Comment: am facing one more issue in this command. it replacing

Comment: I have another statement  Address.WorkName,  it is converted as Address.Work"Name",  it should not do.

Comment: sed '/[[:alnum:]_-]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]\{,1\}Extension,/ s/Extension,/"Extension",/I'

Comment: @asalthangam apologies I had a typo (`\{,1\}` should have been `\{1,\}`) - see edited version